# What is the Equivalent of Windows WMI for MacOS C++ Development?

Tags: c++, macos, system-information

I have a C++ application that gets detailed system information (processor type, available disk space, other hardware profile info) on Windows using WMI.  I want to perform the same type of operations on OSX 10.5+.  What is the equivalent API or interface for MacOS?

Links to API documentation or tutorials are very welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get information about the Mac system, or are you looking for a WBEM implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query most of that information through the `system_profiler` executable. [Apple's example for querying such informations](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/ProfileSystem/Listings/main_c.html) involves a `popen` call to it, so I guess it's the way to go.

Comment: Seems like the Apple way is a little odd, but it'll do.  Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

system_profiler is not the exact equivalent for WMI. It has only local access. MacOs seem to lack support for that. Luckily microsoft has developer OMI for that purpose https://github.com/microsoft/omi/releases