# WMI Browser for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, wmi

Is there anything similar to the WMI Tools available from Microsoft that will run on Mac OSX?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613369/what-is-the-equivalent-of-windows-wmi-for-macos-c-development

Answer (score 0):

The "Apple Remote Desktop" (ARD) uses WBEM, upon which WMI is built. According to [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), ARD can support system management and reporting capabilities, which is what WMI does for Windows hosts. ARD is [based on OpenWBEM](http://openwbem.sourceforge.net/).